# calling a function in a named namespace from anonymous namespace

Tags: c++

In a file there is an anonymous namespace and a named namespace. Anonymous namespace has some internal function which should not be exposed and the named namespace has some overloaded functions which need to be accessed.

```
//test.cpp

namespace
{
void func() {}
void crazy()
{
   func(a);
}
}

namespace useful
{
void func(int a)
{
    //something
}
}
```

Can someone suggest me how to access a named namespace which is written below it ? Is it okay to access a function of a named namespace from an anonymous namespace ?

Comment: Did you declare the `useful::func(int)`?

Comment: The function `::crazy()` needs to be defined AFTER a declaration of `useful::func()`, not before.

Comment: thanks, I thought there is some better way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare in the relevant namespace before it is used and defined:

```
//test.cpp

namespace useful {
void func(int);
}

namespace
{
void func() {}
void crazy()
{
    useful::func(3);
}
}

namespace useful
{
void func(int a)
{
    //something
}
}
```